# Android Firebase Data Write by Authenticated User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My data is saving in an Android Firebase through Android but when I click the save button my app is crashing. What should I do? I searched a lot but never got a satisfying answer. I am giving my related code here

Firebase Rules:

```
{"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": "auth != null"
           }
 }
```

Java Code for Saving Data in Firebase

```
apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Firebase fire=new Firebase(Configuration.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Firebase userroot=fire.child(fire.getAuth().getUid());

            String name_s=name.getText().toString().trim();

            String contact_s=contact.getText().toString().trim();

            String blood_s=bloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            String city_s=city.getText().toString().trim();
            String country_s=country.getText().toString().trim();

            //String password_s=password.getText().toString().trim();

            Information information=new Information();

            information.setName(name_s);

            information.setContact(contact_s);

            information.setBloodgroup(blood_s);
            information.setCity(city_s);
            information.setCountry(country_s);

            FirebaseUser user=auth.getCurrentUser();
            database.child(user.getUid()).setValue(information);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are now a DONNOR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                        }
                                         });
```

My Configuration
    dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I Checked, but my users are successfully logged in but when i am trying to add data on firebase the app crushes but data is added successfully.i am now real confused about the situation.What should i do to fix it??

Comment: Do you want us to guess what exact error you are getting or can you be so kind to specify it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following way of initialization:

`mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();`

Also check if your user was successfully signed in (this almost the same in case you use custom token or credentials for sign-in process):

```
mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LogInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //sign in successful.
                            } else {
                                  //show what's gone wrong:
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogInActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(task.getException().getMessage())
                                        .setTitle(R.string.login_error_title)
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

P.S. From your code snippet it is hard to see how exactly you initialize your Firebase. What is `Configuration`?

Comment: I updated my post.please just take a look and help me :(

Comment: I need to see your logcat output for this.